Vue3: radio input is checked but doesn't appear checked
I have a radio input with v-model a ref() that, although it is marked as checked, it doesn't appear so in the browser.
<ul id="catalogue-filter-order-list">
    <li v-for="value in values" class="catalogue-filter-list-elem">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input :id="`catalogue-order-by-` + value" name="catalogue-order" class="form-check-input" type="radio" :value="value" v-model="orderBy" />
            <label :for="`catalogue-order-by-` + value" class="form-check-label">
                {{ $t('CATALOGUE_ORDER_BY_' + value) }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

If I console.log(orderBy.value) I get correctly the value of the first radio, and if I check the code it is checked:

but in the browser it doesn't appear to:


I feel like you're confusing a few things but here is a Vue playground.
As you can see, everything is working well but the checked is only set on the 2nd radio.
This is pretty much the behavior that it should have as mentioned here

A Boolean attribute which, if present, indicates that this radio button is the default selected one in the group.

checked should not be updated when you select a new radio input, it is mostly meant for the initial render of your input.
Your issue is probably with some CSS. Try to isolate your issue into a minimal reproducible bug somewhere else.
